# Lower bound for arrangement of hyperplanes

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

There are many questions conserning an upper bound on the number of regions in an arrangement of hyperplanes in general position, but I'm interested in a lower bound for hyperplanes with some extra conditions.

Let $A_1,...,A_k$ be sets of each $s$ parallel hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $d(n,k,s)$ denote the minimum number of regions in such an arangement. We assume that hyperplanes in different $A_i$ are not parallel. Do we know a lower bound to this?

I think $d(n,k,s)=d(2,k,s)$ holds. Further it is clear that $d(n,1,s)=s+1$.

Any idea or source for some more information would helps. Best regards and many thanks in advance.

Here are my own thoughts in dimension two: The parallels from $A_1$ divide the plane in $s+1$ regions. Adding a line from $A_2$ splits this regions, so after adding all the lines form $A_2$ we get $(s+1)+ s \cdot (s+1)$ regions. This is best we can get also for the over $A_i$, so in conclusion we get $(s+1)+ (k-1) \cdot s \cdot (s+1)$ regions. Question: Is this optimal? What if we in dimension 3 we assume that not all planes contain one parallel direction?

Comment: I think the worst case is when all of the hyperplanes are parallel to each other, achieving a minimum of $d(n,k,s)=ks+1$.

Comment: Yes thats true, but what if all the $A_i$ are not parallel to each other, this should improve the lower bound.

Comment: It should be true that $d(2,k,1)=2k$, which is attained when all $k$ lines intersect in a common point. A similar arrangement shows $d(n,k.1)=2k$. This contradicts your $k(s+1)^2$ conjecture.

Comment: In general, you get fewer regions when multiple lines are concurrent. For $s\ge 2$, it is hard for me to come up with the configuration which maximizes concurrency, so I am stumped.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I correct my conjecture to (s+1)+(k-1)s(s+1), since each new family gives at least (s+1) new regions per line in the family and the first family gives s+1. This also fits together with your counterexample.